# Anime: swordsman keeps the sword of the person he defeats

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am looking for the title of a swordsman anime in which a man has many swords in his back, and he keeps the sword of the person he defeats.

Comment: In his back or on his back? He defeats only one person or many?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anime involving a protagonist who considers himself to be a master swordsman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208544/anime-involving-a-protagonist-who-considers-himself-to-be-a-master-swordsman)

Comment: @Jacob [per policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/98028) We don't close story-id as dupes until both are accepted, which isn't the case on either one here. Voted to leave open.

Comment: @Jenayah Thanks, noted. The policy answer says they should only be *closed* as dupes when that's the case. Should I hold off on even flagging story-IDs as dupes until there's an accepted answer? (Btw, in the other question, while the questioner did not click the Accept check, they did say "Thank you @ Jacob C, thats the one", and the policy answer you linked says "If the OP posts a 'yes this is it' comment, that's as good as an acceptance.")

Comment: @Jacob missed the comment on the other Q, my bad. Yes, you should hold off *flags* (which generate a review item), but what you can do instead is post the supposed duplicate as a comment ("see also [link] for more details" for instance). Now that all of this is said however, this went into close queue again for being off-topic, which I didn't catch on first read. Montu, if this anime is science-fiction or fantasy, please [edit] your question to includes said elements (magic? Superpowers?). Otherwise I'm afraid this request isn't covered by this site's scope, and should therefore be closed.

Answer (score 7):

This could be the Duelist from [The Duelist and the Drifter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015136/), an episode of the 2011 Thundercats. From [fandom](https://thundercats.fandom.com/wiki/The_Duelist):

> Nothing much is known about the Duelist other than he loves to duel to
>   win famous and powerful swords. He keeps his collection within a
>   shield that he wears on his back.

and

> The Duelist is a sly and cruel individual who constantly seeks worthy
>   opponents in the way of the sword. When he defeats them he takes their
>   swords as trophies.